# Export matrix with rows named

Tags: matlab, struct

I'm having problems writing a double object from Matlab.

I have a structure named `F`, and two objects into it: `F.data` which is a double object of size `190*100000` and `F.labels` which is a cell of size `190*1`. What I want to do is adding the labels to the double object and write it in a csv file. I'm using `csvwrite()` to export and I´m new in MATLAB so I'd rather a simple solution, but that's not mandatory.

I also tried using `vertcat` and `char(F.labels)` in order to paste it later to my double object but I've failed.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post the code you are using and where getting struck

Answer (score 0):

[`csvwrite`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html) and its slightly more powerful relative [`dlmwrite`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) will only write a numeric matrix to a file - they will not work with mixed numeric and text data.

The best way to save mixed data, I think, is as a [table](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html):

```
% Generate example numeric data
F.data = rand(190, 100000);
% Generate example row labels
F.labels = arrayfun(@(x) sprintf('Row%d', x), 1:size(F.data, 1), 'UniformOutput', false).';

% Put the data in a table
T = array2table(F.data, 'RowNames', F.labels);
% Write the table to a csv file, including row labels but not column labels
writetable(T, 'myoutput.csv', 'WriteRowNames', true, 'WriteVariableNames', false)
```

Note that:

- you won't be able to open this CSV file in Excel, because Excel can only handle 16384 columns
- creating the table is fairly fast, at least on my computer, but if you accidentally ask MATLAB to display this table - for example by leaving out the semicolon on the end of the line - it will hang up for minutes or more (I got bored of waiting and used ^C to cancel it).

For this to work you will need enough memory free to copy the whole array into the table structure, which takes more than the original array. If that's a problem you'll have to look at looping over the data and labels arrays and using [low-level file I/O functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/writing-to-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html) to format and write one row at a time.